# Making bullets like in slide master

Tags: vba, powerpoint, powerpoint-2013

I created a slide master textbox where:
* the first level of text is bold
* the second level has a bullet (w/ indentation)
* the third level has another bullet type (also w/ indentation)

However, I have no idea how to recover this formatting once I insert a slide from this layout.

**Here is my slide master layout:**[image]

Once I write text, I have no idea how to obtain the same bulleting and spacing. Below is a description of my keystrokes and how things go wrong.
[image]

As described above, when I try to use the bullet point button, I don't obtain the same bullet points that I specified in my slide master.

Note: I am using Powerpoint 2013, but I have the same trouble when using other versions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ANSWERING OWN QUESTION:

The fix was very basic. Instead of using the "Create bulleted list" button to move to the next indentation level, I needed to use the "Increase list level" button.

As for the undesired behavior from using tab, tab only changes the indentation level once you're in the environment of list levels (which you enter after clicking that button).

Answer (score 0):

This is more a question for SuperUser but my guess is that you've modified the Slide Master, but not the specific Layout that your slide is based on (Title and Content most likely).

Try modifying the Layout.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the comment. It was actually much simpler than that, I was using the "create bulleted list" button instead of the "increase list level" button. I appreciate your help!